# Zookeeper Is it possible to watch on node that Does not exist

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I saw in the zookeper C binding that one of the events is ZOO_CREATED_EVENT.

So i assumed that when i set watch on path without real node - and then the node created - i will get "created event". but when i try to do it (Set the watch and then create the node) nothing happened.

So is it possible? and if no when the "create-event" is triggered?

thanks a lot,

eyal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i found that is possible with the c binding .

if you use the  `zoo_awget` function you will not be notified about create event. but if you use the `zoo_awexists` the watch will triggered when the node will created.

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can watch a node that does not exist using NodeCache of Curator (Java library).

Otherwise the ZK Java binding (and I suppose the C binding too) does not provide anything to watch a node that does not exist.

The created event is fire when a child node is created under the watched node.

Comment: Hi , i found how to do it with the C binding (see my answer). it's interesting how they made it in Curator - if it's not supplied in the java binding.